# How to get json data from azure blob storage and send it to power apps dataverse using azure data factory

Tags: json, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, powerapps, dataverse

I have JSON data in azure blob storage container. I want to get the data and create a table in power apps dataverse and store the data in that table. I am using Azure Data Factory for this. How can I do this?
For eg: this is the json data

```
{
  "name": "Apple",
  "type": "Fruit",
  "weight": "100"
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Name   Type    Weight
Apple  Fruit    100
```

Answer (score 1):

Input file in blob storage.

[image]

Create table in power apps.

Create Pipeline in ADF with Copy activity.

[image]

Add JSON file as Source and Power App as Sink.

Create Linked service as shown below

[image]

Provide necessary details.

[image]

Import Schema in Mapping tab. And Map both Schema as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Finally run Pipeline.

[image]

Comment: I cannot find the Service principal id and Service principal key. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Azure, create an application registration and set the API permissions to be able to access Dataverse/Power Platform.
2. Create a secret for this application registration
3. In your dynamics environment, add an application user and use the client ID from your registration.
4. Assign appropriate rights to access the tables it needs.
5. The Service principal ID is equal to the object id and the secret is your your client secret.